# Find the number of sets $X$ which can be formed by the number $n$

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of sets $X$ which can be formed by the number $n$ where $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $a+b+c=n$.  $a,b,c$ are natural numbers and so obviously $n$ is also a natural number. $n>2$

Comment: No condition on the numbers $\;a,b,c\;$ ? Infinite...in fact, $\;2^{\aleph_0}\;$ ...

Comment: Is $0$ a natural number here?

Comment: This is related to the Sterling number of the second kind and thus might be hard to solve. Basically, the difficulty is that you don't take ordering of the summards into account. If you did, then it would be easy to get an answer by the "stars-and-bars" construction.

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b,c>0$, then this is precisely the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $S(n,3)$.

If any of $a,b,c$ can be zero, then is it the sum $S(n,3)+S(n,2)+S(n,1)$.

As further explanation:

Take any finite set $N$ of size $n$. Then $a+b+c=n$ with $a,b,c\geq 0$ implies that $0\leq a,b,c\leq n$, and thus each of $a,b,c$ can be associated with a subsets $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $A,B,C$ are all disjoint and $a+b+c=|A|+|B|+|C|=|A\cup B\cup C|=|N|=n$.

This shows that every triple can be thought of as a partition of $N$ into three (possibly empty) subsets of $N$ (note that a partition automatically includes the pair-wise disjoint condition).

Stirling's number of the Second kind only looks at non-empty subsets, so we need to look at the partition into three non-empty subsets, two non-empty subsets, and into one non-empty (trivial) subset.  Since $n>2$ we can guarantee that any partition contains a non-empty subset, so this covers all of the cases.

Comment: How can we solve sterling number? Can you suggest me something?

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria The Wikipedia article gives you a way of computing it.

Comment: @Goos I didn't get any indepent formula for $n$.

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria There's not always a simple independent formula.  But [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Explicit_formula)'s the explicit formula.

Comment: no this is not Stirling's number.....This is partition of a function in three numbers and explict formula is ${n^2/12}$ where {.} is nearest integer function.

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria please see edited answer.  Stirling's Number of the Second Kind $S(n,k)$ is precisely a partition of a set of size $n$ into $k$ non-empty subsets.